# SVG image is not capturing on jQuery screenshot - Compatibality between svg and html canvas .

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Recently i write some code for to generate screenshot using Jquery .

Please check my code .

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Scrrenshot</h1>
  <div class="img-div"><img src='http://svgur.com/i/1tf.svg'></div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="generate();">Generate Screenshot »</a>

<script>

$(function(){

jQuery('img').each(function(){

    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');

});



(function(exports) {
    function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
        if (!nodeList.length) {
            return [];
        }
        var attrName = 'href';
        if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
            attrName = 'src';
        }
        nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function(el, i) {
            var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
            if (!attr) {
                return;
            }
            var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
            if (absURL) {
                return el;
            } else {
                return el;
            }
        });
        return nodeList;
    }

    function screenshotPage() {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        html2canvas(wrapper, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, 'myScreenshot.png');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function addOnPageLoad_() {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
            var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
            var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
            window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
        });
    }

    function generate() {
        screenshotPage();
    }
    exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
    exports.generate = generate;
})(window);


});
</script>
```

**style.css**

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);
$red: #e74c3c;

*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
   @include box-sizing(border-box); 
}

html, body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   color: #a8a8a8;
   @include text-shadow(1px 1px 0 rgba(white, 1));
}

form {
     border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}

  input, textarea {
     border:0; outline:0;
     padding: 1em;
     @include border-radius(8px);
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 1em;
     font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
     @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(black, 0.1));
     resize: none;

    &:focus {
       @include box-shadow(0 0px 2px rgba($red, 1)!important);
    }
  }

  #input-submit {
     color: white; 
     background: $red;
     cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
       @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px 1px rgba(#aaa, 0.6)); 
    }
  }

  textarea {
      height: 126px;
  }
}


.half {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.right { width: 50%; }

.left {
     margin-right: 2%; 
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .half {
     width: 100%; 
     float: none;
     margin-bottom: 0; 
  }
}


/* Clearfix */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.half.left.cf > input {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Here the problem is when I click the download button it take screenshot of the wrapper div  without capturing the replaced svg image .

Why the svg image not coming in screenshot? . What changes I need to done  for correct it ? Please help .

Why svg image not compatible with html canvas . ?

Comment: I'd guess that the reason is the Same Origin Policy as the SVG seems to originate from a different domain than the rest of the page.

Comment: no , it's not about the domain. Even i try using image on my localhost, same domain  etc .

Comment: I think it's because of the svg converted into inline svg . But i don't know how to solve this . But i nee to convert svg to inline svg and then take screenshot .

Comment: yes i need to convert to inline svg for some other reason . Img is working fine . That i checked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that , the issue is related to the `html2canvas` version (0.4.1) you are using.

You should upgrade to the latest pre-release of the library , which is **[html2canvas 0.5.0-alpha1](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/0.5.0-alpha1)**.

You would also need to include [**html2canvas.svg.js**](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.svg.js) in your project  to render the inline SVG element properly.

Here is a **[working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bqukhff/)**

Comment: Thank you friend . But it is not capturing svg image screenshot . I tried . Even in the given js fiddle also it is not working .

Comment: It's working for me tho. Have you changed anything in the fiddle?

Comment: friend now i check with google chrome . In google chrome it is working . But in Firefox it is not working. How i can ensure that browser compatibility .

Comment: seems like there are some issues with *html2canvas* library and with firefox also *(the way it renders svgs)*. will let you know if I find any fix for that.

Comment: @GRUNT html2canvas is awesome but I cannot access more than one svg elements in single page. It just takes 'svg' but I have no clue how to access multiple svg elements.

Comment: I also tried with last version of libraries but nothing: https://jsfiddle.net/bhc4f3vn/

Answer (score 1):

It is better to get svg as text and convert it to png and then take canvas or png directly for download via url.
It can be done as follows:

```
<script>
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="'+png+'"/>';
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
};
img.src = url;

</script>
```

where you need to create empty **canvas** or **png-container** inside html.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

or

```
<div id="png-container"></div>
```

Have a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844)

> However, I could not access more than one svg elements in single page.
>   It just takes 'svg' but I have no clue how to access multiple svg
>   elements. See here I have asked a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732307/how-to-covert-multiple-svg-to-png-in-single-html-page) on that.